# Elastic search, Filter is not working using java.sql.Time object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Even though Time format in query and data are same still ES is not giving any result, Can you please check and correct me any thing wrong in dealing with java.sql.Time objects from Java

Query sample is given below :

```
 GET /regularride/regularride/_search
    {
      "size": 5000,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "range": {
                "monday": {
                  "lt": "10:36:00 AM"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "monday": {
                  "gt": "08:36:00 AM"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

and available data in database is shown below :

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":3,"successful":3,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":45,"max_score":1,"hits":[{"_index":"regularride","_type":"regularride","_id":"26201","_score":1,"_source":{"vehicleNumber":"5656","vehicleModel":"Hatch Back","farePerKm":4,"availableSeats":4,"noOfPassengers":0,"vehicleType":"Car","cumOverlapDist":0,"riderHasHelmet":false,"fromDate":"Nov 28, 2018, 12:00:51 AM","processedDate":"Dec 11, 2018, 12:01:51 AM","duration":51,"monday":"10:06:00 AM","tuesday":"10:06:00 AM","wednesday":"10:06:00 AM","thursday":"10:06:00 AM","friday":"10:06:00 AM","dateType":"ALL"}},{"_index":"regularride","_type":"regularride","_id":"26606","_score":1,"_source":{"vehicleNumber":"cufufu","vehicleModel":"Hatch Back","farePerKm":4,"availableSeats":4,"noOfPassengers":0,"vehicleType":"Car","cumOverlapDist":0,"riderHasHelmet":false,"fromDate":"Nov 29, 2018, 12:00:00 AM","processedDate":"Dec 11, 2018, 12:01:00 AM","duration":24,"monday":"07:07:00 AM","tuesday":"07:07:00 AM","wednesday":"07:07:00 AM","thursday":"07:07:00 AM","friday":"07:07:00 AM"}}]}}
```

Comment: I suppose you should use `POST` method instead of `GET`

Comment: Also what is the data type of `monday`. Share the mapping of your index.